# Not getting output in R Shiny app even after changing values and pressing submit button. What should be the required changes?

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I am new to R Shiny coding. I made an app on MATLAB and now trying to replicate in R.
The general code is below ,When running the app no output is given in the main panel only heading is there, please do tell all the mistakes done.
P.S. Don't worry about the iteration loop I have changed it a bit.

**Agenda of app** : take input from user; get values related to input from excel file ; do calculation and display final answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
dataTable <- read_excel("file.xlsx")

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(


    titlePanel(" App"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
    
    selectInput("a_name","A",choices = c('x','y','z'),width = '30%'),
    textInput("a_w","A  %",value=0,width = '30%'),
    selectInput("b_name","B",choices = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'),width = '30%'),
    textInput("b_w","B %",value=0,width = '30%'),
    selectInput("sys","System",choices = c('a','b','c'),width = '30%'),
    textInput("vol","Product",value=0,width = '30%'),
    textInput("area","Area",value=0,width = '30%'),
    numericInput("d","D",value = 0,min=0,max=50,step=1,width = '30%'),
    submitButton('Calculate')
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    ("Output Number"),
    dataTableOutput('OutputNumber')
    )
    )
    
    
        )
        server <- function(input, output) {
            
            n_final <-reactive({
            
            y <- dataTable[,c('C1')]
            z <-which(y == input$b_name)
            m_b <- dataTable[z,c('C2')];
            m_a <- dataTable[z,c('C3')];
            l_p <- dataTable[z,c('C4')]
            a_m <- dataTable[z,c('C5')];
            w_f <- dataTable[z,c('C6')];
            
            # Basic Calculations to give idea
            b_u <- input$b_w/input$d; 
            a_u <- input$a_w/input$d;
            rand_num <- 0.0000001+(0.000001)*runif(1, 0, 1);
            loopCounter <- 0; # Fail safe to prevent infinite loop
            value = rand_num + b_u -a_u -0.99292;
            #Iteration
            while ((value >= 0.00001109) && (loopCounter<10000000))
            {
             b_u <- input$b_w/input$d; 
            a_u <- input$a_w/input$d;
            rand_num <- 0.0000001+(0.000001)*runif(1, 0, 1);
            value = rand_num-b_u -a_u +0.99292;
            need <- 0.82828*rand_num + 99.08


            }
            return(n_final)
            })
            output$Number <- renderDataTable(n_final)
             
            
        }
        shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Comment: What I notice at first glance is that when you refer to `n_final` you need to use the proper format which would be `n_final()`, you do this wrongly at the `output$Number` line

Comment: @Wietse de Vries is right. `n_final` is a function, so you need to use it as a function. But I also see that you use `dataTableOutput('OutputNumber')`, so the id is `OutputNumber`, not `Number`. You should use: `output$OutputNumber <- renderDataTable(n_final())`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion .After making changes this occurs:                                                                         
 Warning: Error in /: non-numeric argument to binary operator
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: set `browser()` on top in your reactive and run the code line by line. there is probably a string in your mathematical operation. this occasionally happens since some shiny inputs do send strings to R even though they are numbers. in this case, just wrap them in as.numeric

Comment: after putting as.numeric values in the while loop this error is happening...:Warning: Error in while: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed...                                                                    The expression in while is a<=b . it should return true or false only, I dont get it

Comment: Can you share sample from  the data in excel?

Comment: Change in code(Only names) :                                        
 selectInput("b_name","B",choices =c('1A','2B','3C','A&B','Example','A2B','7A'),width = '30%'),                                                                                                                         
  Rough alike data is as given below                                                                      https://imgur.com/a/ZvF6Y5c